# Soldering headphone wires with another wire

Tags: soldering, wiring, headphones

[image]

I am trying to solder the wires of a headset back into another wire with the exact same wiring but I’m unsure how to approach the wires that shield the copper wire.

There also seems to string in the wiring.

Do I just ignore the shielding and just slap solder onto each individual wire and connect it to same wire on the other end or am I supposed to move the shielding aside and only side the tiny copper cable inside?

Edit:

I have connected the wires together but am unsure how to isolate each individual wire. Currently I'm using electrical tape on each individual wire but some of the solder are touching another wire's solder leading to interference.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how:

1. The string ends are to be trimmed.
2. The shield wires are to be unwound from the cores and twisted.
3. The core ends are to be stripped of insulation.
4. During soldering, the heat of the soldering iron tip will burn the insulation on shield wires.
5. Each core / shield is to be soldered to the terminals of a headphone element.
6. At the headphone jack, the shields are to be twisted and soldered to the jack barrel terminal while the cores are to be soldered to the remaining two.

Comment: As you're giving him s tep-by-step, you might want to add ... (4) Heat the bare copper at the cut ends with a blob of fresh solder to heat the shield wires, just heating from the insulation will likely fail, as in not get the wire hot enough to burn the insulation off. (6) Take great care that the soldering heat doesn't melt the insulation to the core wire. The ability to be able to do this will likely need the experience of half a dozen failed attempts!

Comment: Thank you, @Neil_UK!

Comment: This passive voice is a strange way to write instructions. Usually you write: "1. Trim the string ends. 2. Unwind and twist the shield wires from the cores. 3. Strip the core ends of insulation." etc...

Comment: Thank you for your observation, user253751. I generally write that way and have followed the same by rote!